# How can I make a script retrieve specific data from a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, database, get, mysqli

I made a simple search to retrieve customer data from a database. So far I've only been able to make it successful display the current table data on the webpage but I can't get the search function to retrieve specific data. I'm having 0 database access issues.

I've been searching on goggle for hours and trying many different combinations but I can't find any decent tutorials on making a  mysqli search.

[Link to my current php page](http://www.teetimelawncare.com/search.php)

Cust_no is primary key(varchar), prog_id(integer), balance(varchar)

```
 **Table structure**

Query Output:

> SELECT prog_id, cust_no, balance

FROM `tee`.`teecust`

+ ------------ + ------------ + ------------ +

| prog_id      | cust_no      | balance      |

+ ------------ + ------------ + ------------ +

| 220852       | 1184631      | 0
           |
| 220853       | 1184693      | 0
           |
| 225726       | 1186292      | 0
           |
| 220854       | 1233446      | 0
           |
| 220856       | 1233672      | 0


<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <title>Search the Database</title>
        </head>



  <body>
      <form action="search.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_self" id="search">
          Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

 <?php

    $host="****";
    $port="3306";
    $socket="";
    $user="u*****";
    $password="*****";
    $dbname="tee";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $query = "SELECT cust_no FROM teecust LIMIT 20,5";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        /* fetch associative array */

     while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            printf ("Customer Number:%s   Billing ID:%s   Balance due:%s\n", $row["cust_no"], $row["prog_id"], $row["balance"]);
    }
        /* free result set */
        $result->close();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need a more complex SQL query, specifically, you'll need to learn about the WHERE clause: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Hello @WillWIlkinsIII !As i can see when i access the link that you have provided to your page , this warning : Unknown column 'term' in 'where clause' so i could guess that your sql is malconstructed so can you please tell me if the code posted here is the same used in the page you point to and if it is the same why in this code we could not find neither a where statement neither a term word so if the both are different so can you please explain what is the relation of your code posted here with the page you have provided a link to it ? So we can be more in the environement of your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the search criteria via `get` - since that is what you specified. Although you didn't mention this in your post, I'm assuming you want to use the search criteria in your query:

Extra note: You may also want to read up on the [where clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) in SQL

(I've shown you how to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for added security)

```
    <?php
            $searchTerm = $_GET['term']; // GET the search term submitted by the form

            $customerNumber = '';
            $progID = '';
            $balance = '';

            // build your query - notice the user of '?' as I'm using prepared statements to query the database. Also notice the 'where' clause.
            $sql = "Select cust_no, prog_id, balance From teecust where cust_no = ?";

            // Create the prepared statement
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $searchTerm); // bind the search term to the query where the '?' once was
                if(!$stmt->execute()){ // run the query
    echo $mysqli->error;
    }
                $stmt->bind_result($customerNumber, $progID, $balance ); // retrieve results into variables
                while($stmt->fetch()){ // loop through results
                    // You now have the result in $customerNumber, $progID, and $balance - do what    you want with it
echo "customer number: " . $customerNumber . "<br> Program ID: " . $progID . "<br> Balance: " . $balance;
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        else{
        echo $mysqli->error;
        }

            ?>
```

Comment: I made some changes but I still get nothing:


$customerNumber = '';
$progID = '';
$balance = '';

$sql = "Select cust_no, prog_id, balance From teecust where term LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'";

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII I don't understand the issue. could you please try to explain it in other terms?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the row...the primary key(cust_no) is an integer...maybe that's why I get nothing? I tried where term=cust_no"; but I get nothing.

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII I think you should really consider starting with the basics as it doesn't sound to me like you understand what's going on here. It makes no difference what type the values are that you're trying to retrieve from the database. If you're trying to receive the row, you would use the select statement just like I've shown you, the only difference would be the name `term` - that may be different based on what you used in your database.

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII you should edit your question to show the format of your table

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII see my latest edit - it includes some error handling. If the query doesn't run correctly you will get an error message.

Comment: I got the error message(Unknown column 'term' in 'where clause' ), table is up. Database is Mysql hosted on amazon RDS

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII Like I said, `term` represents a column in your database that you want to filter the results by, that's the entire point of searching :) So, what column are you using to search for? If the user enters some data in your search field, what exactly are you searching? I'll need to know that in order to update the query :)

Comment: They're searching for the customer number which would pull up the row with their balance and prog ID. We want customers to be able to check their balance.

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII ok, I've edited my answer. See how `term` changed to `cust_no` ?

Comment: I tried....nothing....I secretly suspect that it's the html not displaying the results. I've probaly put over 30 hours and tried every mysql combination or tutorial I could find.

I even hired a professional and he failed. All I've been able to do is just get it display the table contents....nothing else.

It's like gordian's knot!

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII I will build you a full example on sql fiddle ... The chances of the html being wrong are slim to none.

Comment: perhaps my table is totally effed up?

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII Are you still getting the MYSQL error? If not, the table is fine and so is the query. Notice that in the answer I posted I am not **displaying** any information, if you want I can add that to the code.

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII I updated the answer to actually ***output*** the data returned from the Query. When you query a database with PHP, you need to tell the script to display the information (if you want it displayed), it won't do it by itself.

Comment: You're welcome - I just went through all your questions and upvoted so you would have enough reputation to chat - guess it was perfect timing :p Take care, good luck.

Comment: @WillWIlkinsIII as you an see, using mysqli is a pain in the back. That's why you have to use PDO, which will make your code 5 times shorter and less error-prone

Comment: @YourCommonSense There is nothing wrong with mysqli - ... all preference. Also, I think it's a good way to learn some basics.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm finally starting to get the hang of PHP I think.

Answer (score 1):

> There is nothing wrong with mysqli - ... all preference.

Surely it's a matter of preference. If one prefers bloated, non-reusable and insecure code, mysqli is their choice. But if they want something otherwise, then [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) have to be chosen:

```
$sql = "Select cust_no, prog_id, balance From teecust where cust_no = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['term']));
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "Customer: $row[cust_no]<br>
          Program ID: $row[prog_id]<br>
          Balance: $row[balance]";
}
```

Comment: Are you really trying to make the argument that `mysqli` prepared statements are insecure? As long as you handle all of the data correctly there is nothing insecure about using prepared statements.